# Updating a pivot table's additional column in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship, pivot-table

I have the following schema:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->mediumText('subject');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->boolean('draft');
            $table->integer('sender_id')->unsigned();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('message_assets', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('filename', 255);
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('message_id')->references('id')->on('messages')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('message_users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('read')->default(0);
            $table->string('folder', 255)->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('message_id')->references('id')->on('messages')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

What I would like to do is update the `read` column in the pivot table to true when the user view the message. I have the controller nailed its just how do I go about getting the relevant record from the pivot and update the `read` field only.

Here is the relationship:

```
public function to()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('SeriousJelly\Modules\Users\Models\User', 'message_users', 'message_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unclear on exactly what you want. A little controller code might be nice to see what you have tried and what you are trying to do.

That said, this may work.

```
$message->to()->updateExistingPivot($user_id, ['read'=> 1]);
```

Using `to` is a little ambiguous, i might use `user` to make it a bit more clear assuming this is on the `Message` model.

The [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) have some good information.

**UPDATE PER COMMENT**

The code below works in Laravel 5 but I am not sure with 4.2.

```
$message->to()->sync([$user_id => ['read'=> 1]], false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have actually tried this but I seem to get no errors and the 'read' field doesnt seem to be getting updated. $this->model->to()->updateExistingPivot($userId, ['read'=> 1]);

Comment: @SeriousJelly I updated my answer per you comments, check it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, but that throws the following error: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'message_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `message_users` (`message_id`, `read`, `user_id`) values (, 1, 1))" *I want to update the row, not insert a new one?

Comment: @SeriousJelly what happens when you dd($message->toArray()) before calling this?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you aren't getting a message. Can you post your controller code in your question?

Comment: Ok, so I solved the problem that was resulting in $message returning nothing and now your solution works! Great stuff! Thanks!